# Rails app with rich text editor with formula features

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rich-text-editor, formulas

I'm writing a web app (**Rails 3**) that is supposed to be some sort of learning portal where you have lessons, test's, ext… Now for a lesson body I wan't to give admin an option to use some rich text editor and what's more it should have some features to edit formulas as we web-site will be all about math.

During my lifetime I've used tinyMCE (as editor), mathJax (as formula interpreter). And I'm thinking maybe it will be nice to store data in markDown and generate html on resource request instead of allowing only certain html tags.

Can this all be solved with gems?
or will it be wise to add tinyMCE the hard way (without gem support) and add MathJax plugin to it?
What else can you suggest?

Comment: have you solved this problem? I've been looking for a couple hours for a RTE that supports math symbols. Best I've found is TinyMCE with [fMath](http://www.fmath.info) plugin. I didn't try to implement it because I don't really like its UI and am hoping for something better...

Comment: @theButler yeah, the best I've found was tiny mce. But also I think that the best solution is to store that data in Markdown and render in each time you show it. So for now I'm using markdown field + preview. (like here on stack overflow)